# Is it possible for a Schengen country to advise the US to cancel/revoke a valid visa?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, embassies

I've posted a longer question on this before but it was put on hold. I thought that it may help if I just ask a more concrete and a general question regarding this issue.

I was wondering if a Schengen country can advise the United States to revoke a valid visa if they discover inconsistencies in an applicant's file. Actually, I was reading on a popular forum in Nigeria about some applicant's experience where a Schengen country (Germany) literally forwarded his file to the US embassy so they can cancel his visa. He also gave me a link in which a popular Nigerian singer got his US visa cancelled thanks to the Germans. This is the link http://www.modernghana.com/movie/332/i-lost-n20m-yinka-ayefele-gospel-singer.html

Now I'm quiet confused after reading this. I know that many country's have information sharing agreements and I'm aware of such agreements between the UK, Canada, US, Australia, etc. But, I haven't came across a similar agreement between Schengen countries and the US. But here is my bigger question.

Every time someone from the "third world" applies for a Schengen visa and if he/she is in possession of a valid US visa, is that person also risking his US visa while they're applying for the Schnegen visa? Can the Schengen countries just forward your file to the US embassy for visa cancellation without any hindrance if they "suspect" something is wrong with your application?

Comment: Is it the same fellow who's band absconded and went underground during their US tour?  Do you think that might have something to do with it? And yes, what they did was legal and Ayefele signed an agreement on his application permitting Germany to do it (i.e., transit visa to the US).

Comment: The article barely has details but it seems like it says this may have been their second refusal for the transit visa (19 people first time, 14 the second; if only 14 needed to go why were there 19 first time round?). Even without knowing the reason for the first refusal it might have been prudent to just pick another route after that one to avoid the issue. It isn't like they had to transit the EU, there are flights from west Africa direct to the US.

Comment: But I think the biggest question is if the Schengen embassies can just pass  your information to the US embassy for visa cancellation everytime they suspect something.  So does that mean that everytime a valid US visa holder applies for a Schengen visa, he is risking the  cancellation of his visa? Just because a Schengen country thinks that you're not a legitimate traveler shouldn't really mean that they lose your US visa as well. I wonder if it's common for Schengen country's to pass information to their US counterparts for visa cancellations?

Comment: I believe every consulate has telephones. If they have information they want to pass on to their counterparts from another country, they can pick up the phone, with or without a formal information-sharing agreement. If it were incredibly common for visas to be cancelled in this way, surely we'd hear about it a lot more, and it sounds like there were particular reasons for suspicion in this case.

Comment: @ZachLipton, I would be surprised if this data exchange went on directly between embassies. That is a national policy decision.

Comment: @Raj, this seems to be a very special, rather mysterious case. Holders of valid US visas aren't now required to get visas for direct airside transit in Germany (were they in 2005?), so it is unclear what it was that they applied for. However, any status justified by the holding of a valid US visa may require checking that the US visa is in fact valid (a cancellation may not be apparent in the passport), which may involve telling the US the circumstances for the check. The existence of an exemption for US visa holders implies some sort of information sharing about that.

Comment: @Dennis Not necessarily, for at least two reasons. Firstly, as of today, Schengen countries still have no systematic records of all entries and exits into the area (there are plans underway to create one) so they rely on what's in the passport itself to a much greater extent than what you might suspect (or modern technology allows). […]

Comment: Secondly, airside transit visas aren't checked *at all* by border guards (we have some questions about that in the archive), they are designed to be checked by airlines and those definitely do not have access to official databases or any obligation to communicate passenger manifests to the destination country (like entries and exits, there are national systems in some but not all countries and no Schengen-wise system to collect such data).

Answer (score 4):

There is definitely no data exchange between Schengen countries in general and the US and no legal basis for the US to have (official) access to the main Schengen databases (SIS and VIS). But individual countries can pass on intelligence and it's up to the US what to do with it.

And among European countries, Germany is, beside the UK, one of the countries with the closest relationship with the US as far as intelligence sharing is concerned (historically, the [main German intelligence service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Intelligence_Service_(Germany)) was set up by the US to reuse older German spy networks, before being handed over to the German government so the links are old and far-reaching). The extent of the collaboration between the BND and its US counterpart (and the extent to which the government was aware of it) even led to a sort of mini-scandal last year.

As far as I know, any information that might have been exchanged between both countries would not usually come in the form of an advice to do anything like cancelling a visa nor would all files be routinely shared with a third country. Rather it would be an informal “we have heard that such and such might have done this”. The decision regarding what to do with it rests entirely with the US.

Comment: But is it common though? Should every US visa holder be concerned when applying for a Schengen visa? Or these type of "tip-offs" are just reserved for serious things?

Comment: @Raj I don't really know but I would suspect it is rather uncommon.

Comment: To call inconsistencies in a visa applicant's file "intelligence" is a bit grandiose.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi "Intelligence" is often a somewhat grandiose name for what it is but in any case that's the kind of information exchange that goes on. I can't tell what the problem exactly was from the question itself and I did not follow the link but I know that if it really led to the cancellation of another visa, it wasn't a mere inconsistency (the comments suggest some scheme to secure visas for unrelated people?). As I wrote in the first paragraph, there is no routine sharing of the entire visa application database with the US so that interpretation is incorrect.

Comment: Its definitely the exception rather than the norm. I image there has to be some seriously compelling reason - a material fraud or deception or similar that might prompt a "hey heads up about Mr. Suspicious" note between Germany and the US.  Typically other countries don't take the meddling of friends in their internal affairs lightly.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, they can.**

Germany cannot *cancel* an US visa, but it can pass information to the US which leads the US to cancel the visa.

Various countries share intelligence information. One well-known example is the "[Five Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes)" group of five English-speaking countries, but similar sharing happens bilaterally and within NATO (which includes Germany and the US).

Intelligence information includes not just terror threats but also information on suspected or confirmed crimes. Legal action is possible if one thinks that the information was wrong, but that will usually get nowhere -- countries don't discuss intelligence matters much.

Comment: I don't think this type of information exchange has anything at all to do with NATO. It would be negotiated and organised bilaterally between some countries.

Comment: I think that Germany is not a part of the Five eyes group, according to the Wikipedia but I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Raj, to the best of my knowledge Germany isn't in Five Eyes. I'll clarify.